# in TAILS, TOR launcher shows error "unable to connect to tor port

Tags: tails, update

I am running TAILS 3.2.  When I try to upgrade to TOR 7.0.8 I download the linux64-7.0.8 package.  I am able to unpack the package.  But when I try to run the TOR Browser Setup program, I get an error message "unable to connect to tor control port.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't upgrade to the Linux 7.0.8 package under Tails directly.

Instead, continue to use the Tor Browser provided by Tails.

Tails uses a service called onion-grater which acts as a proxy between applications and the real Tor control port. It limits access both to what applications can talk to the control port in the first place, and it limits what the applications can request of the control port too. This is to allow applications that need it to make reasonable requests of Tor, while helping reduce the damage that could be done if a compromised application tried to interfere with it. Tor Browser, which isn't the Tor Browser included with Tails would be unable to talk to the control port.

Tails also uses a packet filter to stop accidental leaks from reaching the internet. Part of this restricts the amnesia user from making connections to local ports and services. The amnesia user cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:9151, where Tor Browser expects Tor to be listening.